# Where do I find a list of flalign*...commands? text fields? arguments?

Tags: align

There's something called "rlap," whatever that means, but there isn't anything on the internet that simply gives me a list of all the different kinds of alignment...things...to look up that are compatible with the flalign environment in order to align text how I want.

Somehow not even this link has it http://latex.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_environments

Well what if I want an llap for some kind of left align? What if I want a clap for some kind of center align? There's absolutely nothing that describes those possibilities.

Comment: Here there is a guide `amsmath package`: http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/math/amsldoc.pdf see pag. 2 §3 Displayed equations.

Comment: Sure, the minimal work is " \rlap{anything you want}" and then that's it. I'm not asking for any code to be modified, all I want to know is simply what the other options there are, like that one, for the begin{flalign*} environment. If you literally understood nothing, you probably don't know English then and I can't help you with that. How does anyone even know " \rlap" exists? Where is the reference material defining it?

Comment: The "rlap" operation didn't appear in your document.

Comment: `\rlap` and `\llap` have nothing to do with `flalign`, which an `amsmath` multiline environment. They're plain TeX commands, which insert their argument either on the left or on the right of the insertion point, but makes it have 0 width.

Comment: But how do I find a list of which plain tex commands are compatible within the flalign environment? Is there anything for centering like rlap? In fact I typed in "llap" and nothing changed after running the script.

Comment: Centerin like `\rlap` can be done with `\makebox[0pt]{...}`, or `\clap`, defined by package `mathtools`, along with `\mathclap`, `\mathrlap` and `mathllap`.

Comment: `\rlap` and `\llap` are documented in *The TeX Book*, though obviously not `flalign`.

Comment: There is also \mathrlap, \mathllap and \mathclap in the mathtools manual.  Every package you load comes with its own mnaual, although finding them can be difficult.  I created a folder that contains nothing but manuals and links to manuals for easy access (especially if I can't remember how to spell the names).